# How do I access uploaded files on Microsoft Azure websites?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I wanted to upload some audio files to my azure [ASP.NET] website. I then came up with this idea: I created a WebAPI action responsible for uploading the audio files into an `UploadedAudio` folder that I created inside the `Content` folder (wich is a public folder, right?). Everything is working just fine in Debug mode.

After publishing to Azure, I can see that the files are persisted with paths like `D:\home\site\wwwroot\Content\UploadedAudio\5ab46baa-ffa7-4b7f-bbb9-9d0c53fa0751.mp3`, but I'm not able to play them like I can in Debug mode, because I get a `NotFound` error. Here is the URL  that I use `https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/Content/UploadedAudio/5ab46baa-ffa7-4b7f-bbb9-9d0c53fa0751.mp3`. In Debug mode, `http://locahost:port/Content/UploadedAudio/5ab46baa-ffa7-4b7f-bbb9-9d0c53fa0751.mp3` is working fine!

How can I access the uploaded audio files?

I hope that my problem is clear enough. If someone can help me with this...

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323548/upload-picture-to-windows-azure-web-site.  You are better off storing these files to Blob Storage instead of the website filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it !! adding these lines to the `web.config` is the solution:

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</staticContent>
```